# Creating a custom permalink structure based on post fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I am wondering if it is possible to create a bespoke permalink structure which is based off some of the custom fields I have in my post.

The custom post fields are: film_director, film_name (these will be consitent through out the website)

So the structure I would like to create is as follows:

http://domain.com/%film_director%/%film_name%/%postname%

I'm not great with Wordpress specific terminology so I might just be looking with the wrong keywords however is this something that can be completed (with use of either a plugin or custom code)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Yep you can do this: here is a [nice tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20161114085835/http://firecask.com/custom-fields-and-posts-in-wordpress-permalink-urls/) about it.

I also find a plugin which seems to do this, but it's quite an old one. http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-fields-permalink/

Comment: I'm wondering if this will change the permalink structure for the entire website or just the posts?